# Building dependency trees

Tags: c++, dependencies

How do I build a dependency tree using C++? By dependency tree I mean, for example, checking what files a certain program needs in order to run. By checking that, I could find if there are any missing or corrupt files.

How do I do something like that?

edit:

I'm not looking for a program that does it for me!

Comment: Thanks, I know that tool, but I'm looking for how to do it on my own. Of course I don't need something as complex as this tool. I just want to build a very basic dependency list.

Comment: Assuming you want to do this for the executable instead of the source code, you'll need to specify the platform (after compilation you care about the executable format, not the source code language).

Comment: I need it cross-platform

Comment: I suppose by needed files you mean dlls and librarys? As the binary-format of different platforms is not compatible you might find it easier to search for one tool per platform (for windows `Dependeny Walker` is a good tool).

Answer (score 2):

There is no cross-platform method for calculating dependencies, because this is not actually a C++ problem. It is related to the executable format output by the compiler, and that is different on each platform.

On Linux (and probably other Unices), the [ldd](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ldd+1) command is what you want. This prints out the (recursive) modules that will be required by the executable, and also tells you where they can currently be found on your system.

On Windows, [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is an excellent graphical tool that lets you explore all of the DLLs that an executable (or another DLL) depends upon.

Comment: Of course, this only detects dependencies on other libraries. If you are looking for *all* the files a program needs to run (such as image files, etc, as well as libraries dynamically loaded at runtime), there is no simple way to do that, since the files are not determined at compile time. On Linux, `strace` (grep the output for `open`) tells you all the files the process opens at runtime, but of course it only tells you about that particular run of the program, not all possible files it will try to open.

Comment: But that still doesn't tell me how to actually build a dependency tree on, say, Windows(let's forget Linux for now because the majority of my users are on Windows). I can do it with a tool, but I'm looking for how to write a C++ program to do it, possibly using a library.

Comment: I don't know how you would do that on Windows. On Linux, it would be easy, because ldd is a command-line tool. You would just open a socket to ldd and read the text that comes out of it. On Windows, people generally build GUI tools which are impossible to access programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion when talking about Windows: you can write a module that catches all the calls to open, read, write, ... a file from your application and builds the list of files requested possibly filtering such files as standard input/output, ports, devices, etc.

You can do this also on Linux (this is even easier than on Windows).

Anyway, I don't realize how you can build an hierarchy (tree).
Just in case: you can use this solution in couple with another one (such as ldd, dep walker, etc).

Comment: If you need general information on this question search with google `Windows API hook`. There are exellent articles by MS-Rem on [wasm.ru](http://wasm.ru/publist.php?list=21#series_8) but unfortunately in russian. Also I found special library written for this purpose [hook-api](http://www.hook-api.com/) but I've never used it. If you need more specific answer (how exactly you can write it, what API functions can be used, etc) just create a new question or mail me :)

Comment: If you can use that module to build a dependency tree, I really need to know how to write it. I guess I'll mail you. What's your email? thanks!

Comment: Note that we have two radically different suggestions here: be careful not to confuse them. The static approach (ldd, dep walker, etc) gets only libraries, but always works. The dynamic approach (catch calls to open) gets all files, but only gets the ones that happen to be opened in that test run, so it doesn't always work.